# Spring Boot register API calls without context path

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an application running on External tomcat where context path will be created automatically for war file name (smth like http://localhost:8080/testApp). I have existing js calls that are calling some existing rest services. These js calls are made in such a way that they **do not include context path** (like http://localhost:8080/v1/getUsersList), but Rest APIs are automatically registered using context path

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/getUsersList")
    public ResponseEntity getUsers....{}
}
```

So for this I will have API registered as http://localhost:8080/testApp/v1/getUsersList

Please advise what to do with this mismatch (pls note I cannot modify code how js api calls are made, I can update Controllers and add some properties in Tomcat conf).
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring : bypass contextPath for a specific controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47137169/spring-bypass-contextpath-for-a-specific-controller)

Answer (score 1):

Use full URL for rest call :-  http://localhost:8080/v1/getUsersList
instead of relative URL :- /v1/getUsersList
When you use relative path for rest calls it assumes that you are calling same application so by default current context will be added 
before relative URL :-  http://localhost:8080/testApp/v1/getUsersList